# Automapper ConstructUsing method is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm having trouble with ConstructUsing method. The field 'Thumbnail' is not changing even after resolving the context. Any suggesstion please?

```cs
var command = Mapper.Map<CreateDeviceApp.Command>(
    model, 
    opt => { opt.Items["Thumbnail"] = uploadImageResponse.Uri; });

CreateMap<CreateDeviceAppViewModel, CreateDeviceApp.Command>()
    .ConstructUsing((src, ctxt) => 
        new CreateDeviceApp.Command() 
            { Thumbnail = ctxt.Options.Items["Thumbnail"].ToString() });
```

Comment: Can you please show the code on how are you registering the mapper-configuration and automapper itself?

Comment: @alsami thank u for your response but  I think that I have found where's the problem, the Thumbnail property is part of CreateDeviceApp.Command and also part of CreateDeviceAppViewModel so what's going on here is that the AutoMapper is ignoring the ConstructUsing method because it just mapped all the properties (including 'Thumbnail' property).

I changed Thumbnail to ThumbnailUri on CreateDeviceApp.Command and it worked.